# Flutter :: How to limit the time in showTimePicker?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm want to build showTimePicker who can show only the times we want.

Comment: Currently there is no way to do this with the Flutter component 
There is an open issue for this currently 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23717

Comment: limit mean u want to show from and to date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    CustomCupertinoTimerPicker(
        startRestriction: startTime,
        endRestriction: endTime,),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?